# Installing ffmpeg for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

I want to use ffmpeg to download a video from Youtube to mp3

The code is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['the_url'])
```

But obviously I get the error: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one.

I installed ffmpeg but my question is do I need to import something now or put path were I saved the .exe

Comment: Do you have the same error after the installation of ffmpeg? You probably need to add the path of the directory that contains the ffmpeg executables to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work

Comment: OK I found the problem I needed to restart Jupyter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot restarting Jupyter. But before you need to  add the path of the directory that contains the ffmpeg executables to the PATH environment variable. I found a video that explains it pretty well on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjtmgCb8NcE&ab_channel=LinuxLeech