# ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm working downloading mp3 from youtube with youtube_dl. I installed ffprobe and ffmpeg through `pip install ffprobe` and `pip install ffmpeg`, but my code still returned the error in the title.

I tried adding the files [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) to PATH, as mentioned in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742244/installing-ffmpeg-for-jupyter-notebook), but it didn't work.

I have also tried using an anaconda environment, but it returned the same error as well.

Here's my code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
songs = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qLL2Gx3I_k','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNeLUngb-Xg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saxxJZCr2-k', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pICAha0nsb0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCmKDK1TYmE']
ydl_opts = {'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio','preferredcodec': 'mp3','preferredquality': 0}]}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(songs)
```

Comment: This question already has answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770155/ffprobe-or-avprobe-not-found-please-install-one